# Which of the following is constant?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

If $f,g$ are continuous real valued functions such that $f\circ g$ is constant then which of the following must be constant?

$$f,g,g\circ f$$

I think when $f\circ g$ is constant then at least one of $f,g$ must be constant then $g\circ f$ must be constant.Is this correct?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can you give some counter example?

Comment: made a mistake; never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
x&\text{ if }x\leq 0\\
0&\text{ if }x\geq 0
\end{array}\right.$$

$$g(x)=x^2$$

$$f\circ g(x)=0$$
$$g\circ f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
x^2&\text{ if }x\leq 0\\
0&\text{ if }x\geq 0
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Yes thanks.Why I can not think so:(

Answer (score 2):

$f$ and $g$ don't need be constant. For example, consider
$f= \begin{cases}
0 \quad &\text{ if } x \geq 0 \\
x &\text{ if } x \leq 0 \end{cases}$
and $g = \begin{cases}
0 \quad &\text{ if } x \leq 0 \\
x &\text{ if } x \geq 0 \end{cases}$